# WPF TextBox detect if text overflowed

Tags: c#, wpf

I try to detect if the TextBox is overflowed. I use code like this:

```
textbox.UpdateLayout;
textbox.ExtentWidth > textbox.ViewportWidth
```

I use it in the following event handlers:

```
Loaded
TextChanged
TargetChanged
```

(binding is using `NotifyOnTargetUpdated = True` and `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`, `IsAsync = False`)

This works fine. Except in one case. If the TextBox starts overflowed it is not detected. If the `Textbox.Text` uses Binding The ExtentWidth is zero, even in the `TargetChanged` event handler. If it is some plain Text like `"123"`, it gets the correct value. What do I miss?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work. `TextBoxBase.TextChanged` sometimes behaves different than expected. Some internal operations are executed *after* the text has changed e.g., caret positioning or measuring. Measuring will affect the `TextBoxBase.ExtendWidth` and `TextBoxBase.ViewportWidth`.

The solution is to defer all custom operations, that are meant to be triggered by the `TextChanged` event. Custom code should be executed after all internal operations of the `TextBox` are completed.
You can defer code execution by enqueuing it to the dispatcher's queue asynchronously. Asynchronous dispatcher operations are executed after all current dispatcher operations are completed:

```
private void TextBoxBase_OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
  this.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(
    () =>
    {
      var textBox = sender as TextBox;
      bool textBoxHasOverflowContent = textBox.ExtentWidth > textBox.ViewportWidth;
    });
}
```